# Repair corrupted JPEGs by writing magic numbers

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, images, jpeg, file-corruption

I recently used both Photorec and Recuva to recover data from an accidentally-formatted 2TB disk, and as a result have a lot of corrupted JPEGs along with those that were successfully recovered.

I've read both [this article](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/repair-and-fix-corrupted-images/) and [this one](https://www.techradar.com/uk/news/software/recover-lost-photos-how-to-repair-corrupt-images-1117764), but as of the time of writing all the products they recommend are paid for and I can't afford to pay for such a product.

Is there a GNU/Bash way I can use to write the JPEG magic number - or even the entire JPEG header - to the first few bytes of (copies of) the corrupted images and see how many of them it fixes? These images are already written off, so I figure it can't hurt to see whether they can be repaired in this brute force way.

Comment: I would suggest trying this: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk worked really well for me in the past where other apps failed.

Comment: ...to the first few bytes of **copies of** the corrupted images ...

Comment: @JanDoggen Naturally, but I'm unsure why that was worth a downvote for my question and what's currently the only answer.

Comment: @Hashim. I dont know either. You are incorrectly assuming the downvote was mine. My remark was just to warn you not to destroy the originals, and to suggest you edit that in.

Answer (score 1):

Fragmentation of a volume causes recovery software to fail that tries to recover files based upon fingerprinting.

Basically the recovery software assembles clusters that do not belong together.
I consider jpeg repair software to be snake oil for jpegs that originate from a recovery.

Answer (score 1):

There's little chance that these files actually contain JPEG data despite the recovery software having them labeled as such. Second, JPEGs from different sources require different headers. So unless all JPEGs on the disk were from one camera or editor and saved with the same settings (resolution, quality etc.) you can not just slap a generic header on and just adding the magic number will not accomplish anything.

Your best chances are, using better software (ReclaiMe, R-Studio, UFS Explorer, GetDataBack, File Scavenger) to do the recovery again. Specially if the drive was formatted say NTFS, using decent software you should be able to achieve a close 100% perfect recovery.

FAT based file systems (would be exFAT in your case) wipe all meta info pointing to specific clusters allocated to specific files, so in that case fragmented files should be expected corrupt after recovery.